# Jquery Serialize not working only on IE

Tags: jquery

With this I listed my codes its working fine in all browsers but not in IE. I searched the stack overflow for solutions still i could not fix. please can some one help me please 
$(this).serialize() returning empty in IE

```
$('Form#UserTripSearch').live('submit',function()
{
    $('#NavDetailHead12').html(HugeLoading);// for loader image
    alert($(this).serialize());
```

// needs to return => type=1&sortby=desc&status=paid&name=peter

```
    var fullurl = $(this).attr('action')+'/'+$(this).serialize();
    fullurl1= fullurl.replace(/&/g, "/");
    fullurl2= fullurl1.replace(/=/g, ":");
    // fullurl2 => sitename.com/type:1/sortby:desc/status:paid/name:peter
    $.ajax({
            type: "GET",
            url: fullurl2,
            data: "ajax=true",
            success: function(data)
            {
                $('#NavDetailHead12').html(data);
            }
        });

    return false;
});
```

HTML CODE:

```
<form action="sitename/search" method="get" id="UserTripSearch">            
    <select id="UserType" name="type">
        <option value="1">User</option>
        <option value="2">Member</option>
        <option selected="selected" value="3">Non Member</option>
    </select> 
    .....
    <input type="text" id="UserName" placeholder="First name, Username" class="TextfiledCommon" name="name">            
        <div style=" float:left">               
            <span class="button">
                <span>
                    <input type="submit" value="Search" id="button" name="button">
                </span>
            </span>
        </div>
</form>
```

Note: My HTML is Fine..

Comment: Can you isolate the problem to a fiddle? Without the html there really isn't much to say here. For example, http://jsfiddle.net/KGa8q/4/ works fine in IE.

Comment: any specific IE version? Also any errors thrown?

Comment: IE all version... not throwing any error. form properly submitting by AJAX in IE.. but serialize shows empty values..

Comment: HTML CODE <form action="sitename/search" method="get" id="UserTripSearch">   
 <select id="UserType" name="type">
  <option value="1">User</option>
  <option value="2">Member</option>
  <option selected="selected" value="3">Non Member</option>
 </select> 
 .....
 <input type="text" id="UserName" placeholder="First name, Username" class="TextfiledCommon" name="name">   
  <div style=" float:left">    
   <span class="button">
    <span>
     <input type="submit" value="Search" id="button" name="button">
    </span>
   </span>
  </div>
</form>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('Form#UserTripSearch').live('submit',function()
{
    formdata =   $(this).serialize();
    alert( formdata); 
    $('#NavDetailHead12').html(HugeLoading);// for loader image
 ..........
 .............
 ................
```

try the above code it should work

You are trying to serialize after replacing the dom. This should be the problem as the intended data doesn't exists. Try this :)

Comment: Thanks Lot now its working fine... I show the loader first and then serialized so only not working in IE

Answer (score 3):

The jquery has the bug on IE 10 (Standard/Quirks Mode), that the .serialize() and .serizlizeArray() can not serialize form data.

```
<div id="showRole">
    <form>
        <input name="roleName" type="text" />
        <input name="des" type="text" />
    </form>
</div>
```

**The fix is:**

```
var data = $("#showRole input").serialize();
```

use div's id to reference the form and serialize the data.

The IE just change the DOM tree and jquery can't get elements.

Answer (score 0):

please check the answer in [Fiddle Link](http://jsfiddle.net/jaSyX/)
This is working fine now ..