# Model is null in Kendo UI MVC in Microsoft Edge and Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, kendo-ui, microsoft-edge

I am using jquery serializeObject to retrieve model binded textbox and dropdown values in my project. In chrome i get the value for both textbox and dropdown however in Microsoft Edge i am not getting any values for the model binded object. In the bottom code, the value of viewModel comes as null for both SupplierName and SelectedSearchType when I use Microsoft Edge however i get the entered value in Chrome.

Any clue why i am not getting any value in Microsoft Edge and IE?

```
<form id="formSupplierInvitation" class="form-horizontal">
    <fieldset id="SupplierInvitation">
        <p style="margin-bottom: 15px;">
            <b>Please enter your search criteria: </b>
        </p>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.SupplierName, new { @class = "col-sm-4 control-label" })
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.SupplierName, new { @class = "form-control", maxlength = 100, @data_toggle = "tooltip", @title = "Maximum length is 100", })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.SupplierName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div class="form-group required">
                    @Html.Label("Search Type", new { @class = "col-md-3 col-sm-4 control-label" })
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        @Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.SelectedSearchType, new SelectList(Model.AllSearchTypeLists, "SearchTypeValue", "SearchTypeText"), new { @name = "DropDownSearchType", @class = "form-control", data_placeholder = "Choose Search Type..." })
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <input id="btnSearch" type="submit" value="Search" class="btn btn-default" />
        <div class="col-sm-12">
            @(Html.Kendo().Grid<SupplierPortal.ViewModels.SupplierInvitationResponseViewModel>()
                .Name("GridSupplierInvitation")
                .Columns(columns =>
                {
                    columns.Bound(e => e.SupplierNumber).Width("160px");
                    columns.Bound(e => e.SupplierName).Width("180px");                            
                })

                .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
                            .Ajax()
                            .PageSize(10)
                            .ServerOperation(false)
                            .Read(read => read.Action("GetSuppliers", "Admin").Data("GetSearchParameters")))                        
            )
        </div>
    </fieldset>
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function GetSearchParameters() {
        return {
            viewModel: $("#SupplierInvitation").serializeObject()
        };
    }

     $('#btnSearch').click(function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();     
            $('#GridSupplierInvitation').data('kendoGrid').dataSource.read();
        });
</script>

public JsonResult GetSuppliers([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest dataRequest, SupplierInvitationRequestViewModel viewModel)
{
    var responseViewModels = new List<SupplierInvitationResponseViewModel>();
    string supplierName = viewModel.SupplierName;
    string selectedSearchType = viewModel.SelectedSearchType;
    return Json(responseViewModels.ToDataSourceResult(dataRequest));
}
```

[image]

Update #1: Followed this post and found this fix. I needed to add 'input' attribute.
[Jquery Serialize not working only on IE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8336965/jquery-serialize-not-working-only-on-ie)

```
function GetSearchParameters() {
            return {
                viewModel: $("#SupplierInvitation input").serializeObject()
            };
        }
```

Update #2: Need to update on my previous update. The previous solution adding 'input' only works for input attributes. (obviousuly). If you have a dropdownlist like above which will get converted to 'select' html attribute, you won't be able to get the value for your dropdown. I believe you can go two ways(?) to solve this. First, read the values by their id, set the values in variable and send those values as individual parameters. e.g.

```
var supplierName = $("#SupplierName").val();
var selectedSearchType = $("#SelectedSearchType option:selected").val();
```

Secondly, use serializeObject and set the properties values in the serialized object.

```
var supplierName = $("#SupplierName").val();
var selectedSearchType = $("#SelectedSearchType option:selected").val();

var supplierInvitationObject = $('#SupplierInvitation').serializeObject();
supplierInvitationObject.SupplierName = supplierName;
supplierInvitationObject.SelectedSearchType = selectedSearchType;
```

Answer (score 1):

There appears to be an interop issue between Microsoft Edge and other browsers when you attempt to serialize from the fieldset. I've authored a short test to help track future support:

```js
var serialized = $('<fieldset><input name="a" value="b"></fieldset>').serialize();

document.body.textContent = ( "a=b" == serialized ? "pass" : "fail" );
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

I have filed an issue for the Microsoft Edge team to investigate the matter further. I'll also be working through [the internals of this method](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/70605c8e5655da996ebd395e3c43423daaa08d9c/src/serialize.js) to more closely identify the point at which Edge deviates from expectations. I will update this answer when I have additional details.

Comment: Are there any solution for it? I tried mvc post with some html editor. When there is a link or image, it posts null as content. Just on Microsoft Edge.